# How to assign two menu items to a single article?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I created 2 menus :

1. Top Menu
2. Side Menu

How can i achieve below 2 tasks:-

1. Assign all the menu items of "Top menu" to "side menu" directly.
2. Create side menu items with the same name as of top menu items.

The problem with this is i want to link the articles with the menu items with same urls, and it is not allowing me to do this.  It is giving error:-

```
"Save failed with the following error: Another menu item with the same parent has this alias"
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand your terminology correctly,

1. Insure that your Top menu has all the items that you want "cloned" on your Side Menu
2. Begin "cloning" the Top Menu items by adding new items to the Side Menu.  The actual joomla term for this is "alias"
3. On your Side Menu, add a new item - the "Menu Item Type" must be *Menu Item Alias* .  From the **Select a Menu Item Type** popup, its at the very bottom, on the right.
4. Once that is selected, you'll be returned to the Menu Item editor, and have a dropdown on the right that will contain the Top Menu items for you to choose from.
5. Choose the one you want to "clone", and make any other changes that you wish that may be available
6. Save the new Side Menu item.

Tada - you have an alias for an existing Top Menu item that appears on the Side Menu. Clicking on the Side Menu *alias* item is exactly the same as clicking on the Top Menu item (it will have the same joomla url), though you can change other settings/styles as the Menu Item editor allows.